# Best practices working with JSON in Go

Tags: json, go

I'm in the beginning of writing a chat app in Go and started wondering what is the best way working with JSON. I've read different articles and it seems like I have to create a different type for every action the client sends.

Lets say there are three actions:

```
NewMessage
DeleteMessage
EditMessage
```

To my understanding I have to create three types that match these actions. Something like this:

```
type Message struct {
    Action string `json:"action"`
    Data map[string]*json.RawMessage `json:"data"`
}

type MessageMeta struct {
    UserId int `json:"user_id"`
    ChannelID int `json:"channel_id"`
}

type NewMessageAction struct {
    MessageMeta
    Message string `json:"message"`
}

type EditMessageAction struct {
    MessageMeta
    MessageId int `json:"message_id"`
    Message string `json:"message"`
}

type DeleteMessageAction struct {
    MessageMeta
    MessageId int `json:"message_id"`
}
```

I come from Node.js world (although I don't want to compare the two) and to me it seems a bit too verbose to create and maintain a type for every action there is. What if there are hundreds of actions?

Answer (score 2):

Go is a strongly typed programming language. There are no loose types like in JavaScript.

If you want a strong data type for each message, then you'll need to write a struct for each type. Otherwise you can unmarshal the message into a `map[string]interface{}` (for "generic" JSON objects) and work with that instead (which will require type assertions to convert the `interface` values into strong types).